# IF does not work in BATCH/CMD FOR loops with FOR variable (ie %p)

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

The following command does not run correctly on Windows Vista and earlier. It works fine on Windows 7 and later.

BATCH example (named `whateveryouwanttocallit.cmd` or `somescript.bat` (extension does not matter in this case)):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%p in ('ping -n 1 127.0.0.1') do if not "%%p"=="" echo %%p
```

The script above is attempting to display only non-blank lines.

On a Windows 7 machine, the following (correct) output is generated:

```
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data: 
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 
Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1: 
Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss), 
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds: 
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

On Windows Vista and earlier the same script produces the incorrect output:

```
ECHO is on.
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:

ECHO is on.
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms  TTL=128

ECHO is on.
Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:

Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

Minimum = 0ms, Maximum =  0ms, Average =  0ms
```

It looks like earlier systems have extra line feeds.
Is there a different output format for earlier systems? Is there a way to accomplish this in a way that works for earlier and later systems? The simpler the solution the better.

Comment: you need double `%` when accessing tokens in batch file...-> use `%%p`

Comment: You should also be using `"delims="` to parse the entire line.

Comment: @npocmaka my mistake, i should have clarified that. the issue persists both in cmd and in batch scripts

Comment: @foxidrive either that or `"tokens=*"`.
neither have an effect on the issue at hand

Comment: FWIW `"tokens=*"` strips leading whitespace so is unreliable for parsing filenames.  It's best to always use the delims instead.

Comment: The syntax hasn't changed in most basic batch syntax since Windows 2K.  What are you trying to do?  Did you call it `ping.bat` ?

Comment: `Neither of the following commands run correctly`, How? What is the difference between what you see and what you think you should see?

Comment: @MCND I added example output. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @foxidrive using `"delims="` or `"tokens=*"` depends on what you are trying to parse. for commands especially there are many cases where you don't want to deal with leading spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on XP

All the lines in the output end, not with 0x0D 0x0A (CR-LF) as usual, but with 0x0D 0x0D 0x0A

There is an aditional carriage return at the end of each line. This does not interfere with your code in the lines with data but generates errors in the "empty" lines.

When the `for` command processes input, if none of the variable/replaceable parameters get data, the line is ignored and the code in the `do` part is not executed. But in this scenario, the lines without obvious content have content, a 0x0D character that is readed and asigned to `%p`. So the line is not ignored, the `do` part is executed, the `if` returns false on the condition as the variable holds content and the `echo` command tries to output a carriage return. But as is, `echo` command interprets the line has no content and `echo on/off` is output to console.

To just avoid the `echo on/off` output to console, use `echo(%p`

To avoid processing the "empty" lines, filter the ping command output

```
for /f "tokens=*" %p in ('ping -n 1 127.0.0.1 ^| findstr /r "[a-z]"') do ....
```

Comment: I knew THAT, now I know WHY. +1 for the very good explanation

Comment: This works as long as the line (`%p`) is not combined with any additional text. But it includes the trailing 0x0D, which could cause problems if you need to append additional characters. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21782435/1012053) for a simple solution that removes the trailing 0x0D.

Answer (score 1):

FOR /F will strip exactly one trailing 0x0D character from each line (if present). So another option is to add an extra FOR /F loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('ping -n 1 127.0.0.1') do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do echo %%B
```